# Hibernate cascade references constraint violation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities.

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name="cities")
public class City  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")

    private long id;


    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country", nullable = false)
    private Country country = null;
    ... //getters, setters
}
```

And the second is for Country

```
@Entity
@Table(name="countries")
public class Country   {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")

    private long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "country")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<City> cities = new BlockingArrayQueue<>();
    ... //getters, setters
}
```

My test code:

```
    Country country = new Country();
    country.setName("USA");

    countryDAO.add(country); //save country


    City city = new City();
    city.setName("New York");
    city.setCountry(country);

    cityDAO.add(city); //save city
    countryDAO.delete(country); //delete country
```

I've expected that delete() had remove cascade fro city, but i get exception:

```
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKTKJBA4WE2I3SH33J3IJK0M60N: PUBLIC.CITIES FOREIGN KEY(COUNTRY) REFERENCES PUBLIC.COUNTRIES(ID) (1)";
```

I'd solved this by rewriting City::setCountry() method:

```
public void setCountry(Country country) {
    if(this.country != null) this.country.getCities().remove(this); //delete from old country
    this.country = country;
    if(!country.getCities().contains(this)) country.getCities().add(this); //add to the new country
}
```

Why hibernate can't do it automatically? Why it doesn't create foreign key for City.Country with **ON DELETE CASCADE**? Is there a way to configure it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Creating the constraint with cascade is a database-dependant feature. As an alternative you can add `orphanRemoval = true` to your `@OneToMany` annotation, so when you call `EntityManager.delete` with the country it will first delete it's child-entities for you.

Comment: So, i've found that adding @OnDelete(action =OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) solved the problem